# SpriteKit Coordinate System Origin

Tags: sprite-kit, swift, skspritenode

I have been trying to place nodes on the screen with the SpriteKit Framework with Swift, however I cannot find where the origin is. I thought it was at the bottom left corner but when I place node3 there it appears to be off screen somewhere. Only node1 appears on the screen, can someone explain what is happening?

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let node = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.greenColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    node.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    self.addChild(node)

    let node2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.orangeColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    node2.position = CGPoint(x: 200.0  , y: 200.0 as Double)
    self.addChild(node2)

    let node3 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
    node3.position = CGPoint(x: 0.0  , y: 0.0)
    self.addChild(node3)
}
```

The SpriteKit Template has the following view configuration:

```
        let skView = self.view as SKView

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
         scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
```

[image]

Comment: try 200.f and 200.f instead of 200

Comment: Sorry mate, same result :/

Comment: Origin is in the lower-left corner. If you get different results check that scene.size matches your view and orientation, and check scene.scaleMode which should be set to aspect fit or resize fill.

Comment: Your first rect, which as at `50,50`, is showing in the center of your view. This probably means that your `size` or `scale` is transforming the view somehow so that `50,`50` is at the center. In that case it makes sense that `0,0` and `200,200` are off screen.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @LearnCoco2D the view and the scene sizes did not match. To Fix the problem I changed the scene.scaleMode to ResizeFill and drew all the rectangles relative to the view and not the scene.

```
scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
```

Comment: Hi
Your node count at the bottom right corner of you screen shot says you only have 1 node attached to the scene.
Are you sure the code you attached to the question matches the screen shot?

Answer (score 1):

The center of the coordinate system if a scene is defined by the `.anchorPoint` value, which is by default `(0.5, 0.5)`, that means that a child node with position `(x: 0, y: 0)` is positioned half the height and half the width of the scene's frame.

Then the upper left corner is `(x: -scene.frame.width/2, y: scene.frame.height/2)`

Then the lower left corner is `(x: -scene.frame.width/2, y: -scene.frame.height/2)`

Then the upper right corner is `(x: scene.frame.width/2, y: scene.frame.height/2)`

Then the lower right corner is `(x: scene.frame.width/2, y: -scene.frame.height/2);`

If you change the `.anchorPoint` to `(0, 0)`, the origin will be placed in the lower left corner, etc.

In your example the green node gets his position from `CGRectGetMidX` and `CGRectGetMidY`, which gives exactly `(0, 0)`, so it's placed in the center of the scene.

I don't know the size of your scene´, the orange node with position `(200, 200)` is possible outside the screen to the `top-right`.
(`"y: 200.0 as Double"` - here the `"as Double"` is not needed).

The red node with position `(0, 0)` has the same position, as the green node. As you didn't set the `zPosition`, it was overlapped by the green node with same coordinates and size.

Answer (score 0):

Your node count at the bottom right corner of you screen shot says you only have 1 node attached to the scene.
Are you sure the code you attached to the question matches the screen shot? Use a print call to detail what the node co-ordinates are in the debug console. Also test to see if the nodes exist

Run a method like this in the update

private func interateNodes() {

for child in children {
     print(child)
  }

}